# Iterating through a dictionary of lists and returning the character at the same index

Tags: python

Working on printing a vertical column from a matrix passed as a string.

I've created a dictionary and assigned each row of the matrix as a value in the dict then bracketed to create a dictionary of lists.

Would like to iterate through each key in the dict and append the value of the given index (e.g. if value is 'a b c', return 'a' for 1, ' ' for 2...) but all I keep getting is:

```
[['a b c '], ['a b c '], ['a b c ']]
```

Or variations on this when I fiddle with it. It never seems to get past row 1, although each value is clearly a different row in the matrix.

Appreciate any help.

```
def column (str, index):
    output = []
    li = str.split("\n")
    row_dict = {
            1: [li[0]],
            2: [li[1]],
            3: [li[2]] 
            }
    for key in row_dict:
        output.append(row_dict[index])
    return output

str = "a b c \n d e f \n g h i"
column(str, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split on `"\n "` because you seem to have a whitespace after each newline.

Getting the nth item of each row is pretty straightforward if you use list comprehensions, e.g. `[row[index] for row in s.split("\n ")]`.

Altogether:

```
>>> def column (s, index):
    return [row[index] for row in s.split("\n ")]

>>> s = "a b c \n d e f \n g h i"
>>> column(s, 1)
[' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Or, if you want it to be 1-indexed (like in the example in the question) instead of 0-indexed:

```
>>> def column (s, index):
    return [row[index-1] for row in s.split("\n ")]

>>> s = "a b c \n d e f \n g h i"
>>> column(s, 1)
['a', 'd', 'g']
```

Comment: this solved the issue and thanks for calling my attention to list comprehension. Now trying to strip out spaces from between chars in my rows using: s = s.replace(" ", ""), but once that line is included, once again it returns single char... e.g. column(s, 1) = ['a']

Comment: @user3763074 Then make sure you change the other split to not have a space: changing `return [row[index-1] for row in s.split("\n ")]` to `return [row[index-1] for row in s.split("\n")]`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the only issue with your code is that you are appending the dictionary value (which is a row, and not the actual value, for example it is getting the row at key = 'index', rather than the value at location 'index' in each of the dictionaries) to output, when you want to assign a particular value from each row... this is what you should be doing:

```
for key in row_dict:
    output.append(row_dict[key].split()[index])
    print (row_dict[key].split()[index])
```

For index=1, this will print:

```
b
e
h
```

This does three things in one statement:

1. gets the string stored at key='key' from dictionary
2. splits your string into individual characters (so you can extract them more easily)
3. Gets the character/word at the index specified by your parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to mention the `key` on which you were iterating. Your function should be something like:

```
def column(str, index):
    output = []
    li = str.split("\n")
    row_dict = {
            1: li[0].lstrip().split(' '),
            2: li[1].strip().split(' '),
            3: li[2].strip().split(' ')
    }
    for key in row_dict:
        output.append(row_dict[key][index])
    return output
```

Also, note that you were adding extra `[]` to the values of the `row_dict`. Finally, iterable objects in Python start from a 0th index, so you would call your function like `column("a b c \n d e f \n g h i", 0)`.

Hope it helps.